# Can I save folds?

Tags: folding

Today I learned how to fold/unfold in Vim; it's quite handy.

Unexpectedly, when I exit a file and reenter it, the folds I created are gone (unfolded).

In our company's large project there are quite a lot of sticky (legacy) code blocks which are kind of obsolete but indispensable.

I really need to fold them nearly permanently.

Is there a brief way to tell Vim to save my folding preferences for a file?

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem, but maybe the `:mkview` and `:loadview` commands could help. You could try adding these 2 lines inside your vimrc `au BufWinLeave *.c mkview` and `au BufWinEnter *.c silent loadview` and adapt them to your specific needs. These are autocommands that will be automatically executed whenever you leave a buffer for the first one, and when you enter a buffer for the second one, but only for C files. I've copied them from the help of the `:mkview` command (`:help :mkview`).

Comment: According to the help, it should restore folds when using manual folding and the option `'viewoptions'` contains `folds`. If you want the autocommands to be executed for other filetypes, you can change the autocommands. For example, if you want to add python files, you could change `*.c` to `*.c,*.py`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong when I said that the autocommands would be executed whenever you enter / leave a buffer. The first one will be executed after a buffer is displayed in a window, the second one will be executed before a buffer is removed from a window.

Answer (score 10):

I do exactly this for one file I refer to a lot `NOTES.otl` I performed the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Useful for my Quick Notes feature in my tmuxrc
augroup QuickNotes
  au BufWrite,VimLeave NOTES.otl mkview
  au BufRead           NOTES.otl silent loadview
augroup END
```

What this means is that in your case you can handle manual folds using the `:mkview` and `:loadview` commands.

Answer (score 2):

An easy to fold the legacy codes permanently is to use the `foldmethod` of "marker".

You can enclose the codes with the markers "{{{" and "}}}", and add a modeline to the file, like:

```
    /* vim: set foldmethod=marker : */
```

Comment: Great. Using `'foldmethod'=marker` is an alternative approach to `'foldmethod'=manual`. Note that the markers `{{{`, `}}}` will be included with the file.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach (not just for QuickNotes but for all files) would be as follows:

```
" Save and restore manual folds when we exit a file
augroup SaveManualFolds
    autocmd!
    au BufWinLeave, BufLeave ?* silent! mkview
    au BufWinEnter           ?* silent! loadview
augroup END
```

For more information, see the [`view-sessions`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#views-sessions), section with includes the `mkview` and `loadview` commands.