# Folding slow with vimtex

Tags: folding, filetype-tex, performance, plugin-vimtex

Automatic folding with the vimtex plugin is unbearably slow.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? I tried installing the [fastfold](https://github.com/vim-scripts/FastFold) plugin but that did nothing I could notice.

Comment: Sorry, what's your actual question?

Comment: Do you want manual and persistent folds? Or do you want to speed up vimtex? These are two different questions...

Comment: I like fold markers

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I would prefer to speed up, but if that is not possible, I would like persistent manual folds. sorry I didn't know asking two related qq. in one was a problem.

Comment: You can save folds over sessions with `mkview` and `loadview`. See [Can I save folds?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/can-i-save-folds)

Comment: Okay; I edited your question to only include the vimtex question. For the other one see: [Can I save folds?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5488/51)

Comment: For marker folding I have the following lines in my `ftplugin/tex.vim`:  `setlocal foldmethod=marker`, `setlocal foldmarker=(fold),(end)` and `setlocal commentstring=\ %\ %s`.
In addition to this I use snippets which all have `% (fold)`,`% (end)` pairs

Comment: @Steve, excellent, I've already started using markers. thanks for the commentstring tip! is there any objective advantege to (fold) over {{{ ?

Comment: I think the default snippets file came with `% (fold/end)` and I got used to it, so I now prefer how it looks. Think that's about it afaik

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: Did you bother to read the vimtex documentation, i.e. `:h vimtex-folding`? The docs clearly point out that the `fold-expr` method of folding is slow, and so therefore provides an option `g:vimtex_fold_manual` which if enabled (set to nonzero value) will set `foldmethod=manual`, and instead will remap `zx` and `zX` to recalculate the folds when necessary (typically not very often).

The fastfold plugin is a very good alternative, as it will automatically ensure that the foldmethod is set to manual. This will also work for other file types, and the plugin provides a set of possibilities for when the folds should be refreshed.

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of vimtex.*

Comment: sorry, I saw it but didn't understand it. I still have two problems with the package, though (for which thanks): first, that it doesn't show the number of lines in a fold, which I find useful; and secondly that using it it takes quite long to load a file. for these reasons I'll stick to markers, which I discovered today.

Comment: You can use standard `foldtext` with `set foldtext=`, which should show line numbers. Also, I personally don't have any problems with long load times that I've noticed. You could consider to open an issue and explain the problem and how to reproduce.

Comment: This worked out of the box for me. Very nice!

Comment: You can try using `foldmethod=marker`. Of course, then you'd have to use a `foldmarker` (e.g. `{{{,}}}` or `F{O{L{D,F}O}L}D`) in tex documents, but it does make it faster.

Comment: I suggest that you do not use markers for folding tex files, especially if you work together with others, as it makes a lot of unnecessary noise. IMHO, folding in vimtex should be fast enough. I also suggest using vim-FastFold, which is a general purpose and better implementation of the mechanisms provided by `g:vimtex_fold_manual`.