# How to 'save' manual folds in vim

Tags: vimrc

Often I will have very long static variables at the top of a file, for example a mapping `COUNTRY_TO_ISO`. I usually fold those mappings with `foldemethod=manual`. For example:

[image]

However, when I save the file, exit it, and re-open it, the folds seem to have disappeared and do not save (even doing `zm` / `zr` doesn't change anything). Why don't the manual folds save by default and how can I make it such that when I open a file it automatically collapses any folds?

Comment: Just a note that the autocommand approach to save/loading views has bitten some folks before when settings were being adjusted that the view overrode. Be careful!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble while approach to folds would you suggest? The files I usually work with are python, and often the folds won't be class/def-based.

Comment: I probably go against the grain here, but I use marker for personal stuff, syntax/indent only occasionally (they’re usually slow for me), and I have custom expressions for some things (markdown headers). But I rarely use folds... my recommendation was really to encourage a more manual use of the view commands so you don’t run into spooky action at a distance/hard-to-debug issues

Comment: I must be traveling the same grain-tangential path as DBK (except I use syntax/indent even less): markers for ad-hoc folding or, for a couple file types, custom expressions. But generally I just don't use them all that much...though that's up from "never" not too long ago.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble cool, I got it to work as well, and then updated to provide a more general answer in the linked-duplicate question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26186/28904.